# How can I fix "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is not a full path and was not found in the PATH"?

Tags: cmake, rust-cargo

I read [Using a Mac to cross-compile Linux binaries](http://timryan.org/2018/07/27/cross-compiling-linux-binaries-from-macos.html) and ran some commands from it. When I run `cargo build` on macOS, I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

How can I fix it?

I tried to set the `CC` environment variable with no success:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ export CC="/usr/bin/gcc"
$ cargo build
```

and

```
$ xcrun -find cc
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
$ export CC="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc"
$ echo $CC
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
```

And then I received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running the following:

```
$ export TARGET_CC=x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
$ echo $TARGET_CC
x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
$ which x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
/usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
$ export CC="/usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
$ echo $CC
/usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
$ cargo build
```